# Azure Pipelines - Commit Tag To GitHub After Long Running Build

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Azure Pipeline which builds a VM DevOps Image, the pipeline takes around 1hr 30 to run due to the size of the image.

I am looking to tag the repo which lives in **GitHub** at the end of the pipeline, however, I am unable to do so, it appears as though the credentials expire after 1 hour.

Please see below code:

```yaml
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  fetchDepth: 0

###### Steps Removed To Save Length.

- pwsh: |
   ## Run CMDS which take over 1 hr.

- pwsh: |
    git config --global user.email "AzureDevOps@AzureDevOps.com"
    git config --global user.name "Azure DevOps Build Service"
    
    git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)

    git add --all
    git commit -m "Example Tag"
    git push origin $(Build.SourceBranchName)

    git tag $(Tag)
    git push --tags
```

When trying to tag the repo, I get the below error:

```
“fatal: could not read Username for ‘https://github.com’: terminal prompts disabled”
```

If I remove the - pwsh: task which takes over an hour, the pipeline runs fine and the repo gets tag.

There is something about **persistCredential: true** which is not working as expected, it appears as though the credentials only last for one hour.

Comment: what kid of credentials do you use ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic persistCredentials: true --- this sets the creds in git config but they expire after 60 mins

Comment: so the OAuth , why don't you use PAT or  GitHub App ?

Comment: @jfdevops, what agent do you use(self? OS?)? as there's a 60mins [timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#timeouts) for Microsoft-hosted agent with private repo, unless you have additional capacity paid for. If it's self one, you can directly store the credentials in machine, for example on windows credential on windows agent.

Comment: @J.Memisevic using a PAT token is more overhead to manage. I don't see how using GitHub App will make a difference, I am using a GitHub App to connect to GitHub anyway. I currently have it working anyway by separating out the git push into another job. Not ideal but works

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT Timeout on the pipeline isn't my issue.

Comment: Thanks @jfdevops. Just want to confirm the agent type. If it's self-hosted one, we could store the credential locally.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT We are using MS Hosted at the moment.

Comment: @jfdevops I think separating out the git push in another job (as you said) is an elegant and viable way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `persistCredentials: true` for `checkout` task, the token lifespan in whole pipeline is `1hour`.

If you `don't` want to use github token to push the code, as you mentioned you can  separate out the git push into another job. Checked on my side, you cannot put the new job in same pipeline, you can publish the repo content as an artifact, and use `pipeline resource` trigger in a new pipeline, download the artifact and push to github repo.